# show badge(textview) on navbar icon(Code added)

Tags: android

I am struggling with this thing from yesterday.
**I need to show a textview(badge) on nav bar icon.**

From where I can set navbar icon?

Anybody know how to do it?

Image for reference: those three horrizontal lines
[image]

**Code for reference**

```
 setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "navbar"?

Comment: I have added image above for reference, nav icon of action bar, I want to replace it with a custom layout . Custom layout will have same icon and a badge floating on it. How to do it?

Comment: There are several different ways to get the setup you've shown. Please post the relevant code and layout.

Comment: well I cannot post code here, Even if you give me Idea if there is any function like setlogoblahblah(R.drawable.layoutfile). then I can try it by myself, and if I stuck then I will post that code

Comment: Can I replace that icon with custom layout in oncreate activitity

Comment: We don't need to see any super-secret code. We need to know if it's an `ActionBar`, a `Toolbar`, something else; whether the three-line icon is static, or a drawer toggle, or a menu button, etc.

Comment: problem is i am not able to find that code, I am not sure which piece of code I need to show you

Comment: but clicking on it opens and closes drawer